# fetchbyId in react wtih redux not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

i have react-app with Redux which uses `Asp.netwebApi` as back-end and uses `axios` .`fetchAll`works but `fetchById` does not work.(i am also confused about `useDispatch` and `useSelector` .I think both fetch data from redux store.).However, I want to workaround and want to get single `tutorDetail` when user click on any `tutor` of `tutorList`.
here is the code of `TutorDetails.jsx` component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {useDispatch,useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { Link,useParams,useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as actions from "../_actions/tutorActions";
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import {storage} from '../firebase';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';



const useStyles = makeStyles({
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
    display: 'flex',
  },
  pos: {
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  card: {
    padding:10,
    marginTop:10,
    display: 'flex',
    flex:1,
  },
  cardAction: {
    display: 'block',
    textAlign: 'initial'
  },
  cardMedia: {
    width: 160,
  },
});

export default function TutorDetails(props) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const[tutor,setTutor]=useState([]);
  const[image,setImage]=useState(null);
  const[url,setUrl]=useState('');
  let {tutorId}=useParams();
  let {fullName}=useParams();
  let history = useHistory()
const dispatch = useDispatch();
//let tutors = useSelector(state=>state.tutor.list)

  //const tutor=tutors.find(x=>x.tutorId==tutorId)
  useEffect(() => {
   let t=actions.fetchById(tutorId);
  setTutor(t);
    setLoading(false);
   
   }, [])
  const classes = useStyles();
console.log("tutor",tutor);
  /// image firebase code here
  storage.ref(`images`).child(`${tutor.tutorId}`).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
    setUrl(url);
    //setImage(url)
   console.log("url:",url);
   
    
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Handle any errors
  })




  ////
  


  return (
    <Card className={classes.card} variant="outlined">
    <CardContent>
    <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
    {tutor.fullName} <br/> 
    {/* <img src={url} alt="tutor photo" height="300" width="400" /> */}
    <img src={url||'https://via.placeholder.com/400x300'} alt="tutor photo" height="300" width="400"/>

      </Typography>
    <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
    {tutor.Qualification} 
      </Typography>
      <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
       category: {tutor.category}
      

      </Typography>
      
     
      <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
         experience:{tutor.experience}<br/>
        subject: {tutor.subject}<br/>
        Mobile: 0343-3969030<br/>
        email: virtualcollegepk01@gmail.com<br/>
        
       city: {tutor.city}<br/>
       
        </Typography>
        <Link to={`/TeacherCourses/${tutor.tutorId}/${tutor.fullName}`}
> <Button size="small" variant="contained" color="primary">View {tutor.fullName} Courses </Button> </Link>
 
              
    </CardContent>
      </Card>
  );
}
```

The `tutorAction.js` code for `fetchAll` and `fetchById`  is here

```
export const fetchAll = () => dispatch => {
      tutorApi.tutor().fetchAll()
        .then(response => {
            
            dispatch({
                type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL,
                payload: response.data
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
export const fetchById = (id) => dispatch => {
    tutorApi.tutor().fetchById(id)
      .then(response => {
          
          dispatch({
              type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_BY_ID,
              payload: response.data
          })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

the `tutorApi` service for back-end calls is as below:

```
import axios from "axios";
import config from 'config';
const baseUrl = `${config.apiUrl}/api/`



export default {

    tutor(url = baseUrl + 'Tutors/') {
        return {
            fetchAll: () => axios.get(url),
            fetchById: id => axios.get(url + id),
            create: newRecord => axios.post(url, newRecord),
            update: (id, updateRecord) => axios.put(url + id, updateRecord),
            delete: id => axios.delete(url + id)
        }
    }
}
```

i will be thankful if someone give me workaround to fetch single `record` for `tutorDetails` if possible.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
export default function TutorDetails(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  tutor = useSelector(state=>state.where.the.tutor.is)
  useEffect(() => {
    //call the action creator with dispatch
    //  and wait until the promise resolves
    actions
      .fetchById(tutorId)(dispatch)
      .then(() => setLoading(false));
  }, [tutorId]);
}

export const fetchById = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  //return the promise
  return tutorApi
    .tutor()
    .fetchById(id)
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({
        type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_BY_ID,
        payload: response.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Even though this is a quick fix I don't think it's the best way of doing this. You should make your thunk actions in a way that it stores loading and error, then you can use those values returned from the selector and set your UI accordingly.

If you have trouble with getting your code to work then please add redux devtools information to your question. Information about what actions were dispatched and what changes it made is very useful for debugging.

Comment: hi @HMR very thanks for help. i have edited the answer to remove extra code. please see the `useSelector` line why it does not render exact tutor imediately.

Comment: Hi @HMR it worked if i use `tutor[0].somevalue` and use `const tutor = useSelector(state=>state.tutor.list)` thanks